# nginx reverse proxy with docker-compose config to serve traffic to multiple domains

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to use nginx with docker-compose to route traffic for two different apps with different domain names. I want to be able to go to `publisher.dev` but I can only access that app from `localhost:3000` (this is a react app) and I have another app which I want to access from `widget.dev` but I can only access from `localhost:8080` (this is a Preact app). This is my folder structure and configs:

```
|-docker-compose.yml
|-nginx
|--default.conf
|--Dockerfile.dev
|-publisher
|--// react app
|--Dockerfile.dev
|-widget
|--// preact app (widget)
|--Dockerfile.dev
```

```
# default.conf
upstream publisher {
  server localhost:3000;
}

upstream widget {
  server localhost:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name publisher.dev;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://publisher/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }

}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name widget.dev;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://widget/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

nginx Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

publisher Dockerfile.dev (same as widget Dockerfile.dev)

```
# Specify the base image
FROM node:16-alpine

# Specify the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# copy the package json from your local hard drive to the container
COPY ./package.json ./

# install dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy files from local hard drive into container
# by copying the package.json and running npm install before copy files,
# this insures that a change to a file does not cause a re-run of npm-install
COPY ./ ./

# command to run when the container starts up
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

# build this docker container with:
# docker build -f Dockerfile.dev .

# run this container with:
# docker run <container id>
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 3050:80
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - publisher
      - widget

  publisher:
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./publisher
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./publisher:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: publisher.dev

  widget:
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./widget
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./widget:/app
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: widget.dev
```

hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 publisher.dev
127.0.0.1 widget.dev
```

Answer (score 0):

why is your upstream trying to connect with
publisher and widget, shouldn't they connect to localhost:3000 and localhost:8080, let upstream server name be publisher and widget but connect them to localhost.

```
upstream publisher {
  #server publisher:3000;
  server localhost:3000;
}
```

Comment: After trying this change it still does not seem to work.

Comment: Restarted nginx?

Comment: Proxy_pass should be HTTP not https

Comment: I changed to http and I stop the running containers anytime I make a change and then run docker-compose up --build but it does not serve on http://publisher.dev. I can only go to localhost:3050 and then I get the react app I want served at publisher.dev